# How can I list sum the last (from the bottom) 5 values in column J for each teams that are in column B (e.g. Crystal Palace)?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is my database.

[image]

I couldn't get anywhere with the helps from other comments with using Sumproduct, probably that is the solution I just can't find it. My goal is to sum the last 5 "scores" from the last 5 games for each team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
= LET(tUnique,UNIQUE(table1[Home_Team]),
score,BYROW(tUnique,LAMBDA(t,SUM(TAKE(FILTER(table1[home_form_PTS],table1[Home_Team]=t),-5)))),
HSTACK(tUnique,score))
```

It sums - per unique team - last five values from home_form_PTS (--> -5 of `TAKE` parameter).

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this was really helpful. I could make it work this way.

Comment: Okay, sorry I'm fairly new here, but I found it.